# D/permissions_handler(16887): No permissions found in manifest for: []15

Tags: permission-denied

Currently having this issue when using flutter share_extend 2.0.0 and Permission_handler 11.0.0
I am trying to share a transaction receipt in my app, it works well on IOS but not android i have added the necessary permissions but it is not working

Looked through my manifest file and still cant find what is wrong

void checkPermission(
{GlobalKey? repaintKey, String? reference, BuildContext? context}) async {
final status = await Permission.storage.status;

```
if (status.isGranted || await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
  print('who granted this ${status}');
  takescrshot(
      repaintKey: repaintKey!, reference: reference, context: context);
} else {
  print('who denied this ${status}');
  if (await Permission.storage.isDenied) {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      takescrshot(
          repaintKey: repaintKey!, reference: reference, context: context);
    }
  } else if (await Permission.storage.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    openAppSettings();
  } else {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      takescrshot(
          repaintKey: repaintKey!, reference: reference, context: context);
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it by upgrading my flutter version from 3.13.0 to version 3.16.7

and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).